VBA Loop through unique values in range based on criteria
As part of my project, I'm stuck with the following.
I need to be able to loop through each unique set of values in a Worksheet, where the criteria is met.



A
B
C




B1
UG
Blue


B2
DG
Blue


L1
Cell 1
Yellow


L2
Cell 1
Yellow


L3
Cell 2
Yellow


L4
Cell 2
Yellow


L5
Cell 3
Yellow


L6
Cell 3
Yellow


S1
River
White



In VBA, I need to get the maximum number of rows where the value in Column C is Yellow.
I also need to be able to loop through each unique value in Column B, where the value in Column C is Yellow.
I think the first part can be achieved with the following:
MaxCells = WorksheetFunction.CountIfs(Worksheets("Location Groups").Range("C:C"), "Yellow")

I guess I then need to do a loop from 1 to MaxCells. But that loop then also needs to do something (for the sake of this example, it could just be a MsgBox with the unique cell value) based on each unique value in Column B where the value in Column C is also Yellow.
In conclusion, a loop with three iterations, because there are only three unique values (Cell 1, Cell 2 and Cell 3) which also match Yellow.

Using Collection is an option.
Option Explicit
Sub Demo()
    Dim objCol As New Collection, rngData As Range
    Dim i As Long, sKey
    Dim arrData
    Set rngData = Range("A1").CurrentRegion
    arrData = rngData.Value
    On Error Resume Next
    For i = LBound(arrData) + 1 To UBound(arrData)
        sKey = arrData(i, 3)
        If sKey = "Yellow" Then
            objCol.Add arrData(i, 2), CStr(arrData(i, 2))
        End If
    Next i
    On Error GoTo 0
    ' print to VBE Immediate Window, change to MsgBox if needed
    If objCol.Count = 0 Then
        Debug.Print "No matching vlaues"
    Else
        Debug.Print "Total Yellow: " & objCol.Count
        For Each sKey In objCol
            Debug.Print sKey ' print to VBE Immediate Window
            ' your code '
        Next
    End If
End Sub


Thank you for this, I have managed to incorporate this to achieve the result desired.

Posting this as a solution rather than a comment so that I can post code.
If that was me I would create a pivot table from the data using column B for "Rows" and count of A for Values.
Then drop C into the filters. On the pivot table itself click Yellow in the filter box (at the very top by itself) - you can then iterate through the Row Labels. Record a macro as you do the first part if you're unsure.
To iterate through the rows of the pivot table use an adapted version of this code (to get the name of the pivot table, click into it then click on PivotTable Analyze in the ribbon - the name will be on the far left of the ribbon)
Sub LoopPivotTable()
'Loops through the "visible" rows of a simple pivot table
    
    Dim pt As PivotTable
    Set pt = ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("Sheet1").PivotTables("PivotTable2") 'Change Me
    Dim rowHeader As String
    rowHeader = pt.TableRange1.Cells(1, 1).Value

    Dim cell As Range
    For Each cell In pt.TableRange1.Columns(1).Cells
        ' Check if the cell is part of the Row Labels area. Don't use the 'Visible' property
        If Not IsEmpty(cell.Value) And cell.Row >= pt.TableRange1.Cells(1, 1).Row + pt.ColumnFields.Count Then
            'Check that it's not the header (allows for that to be overtyped) and not Grand Total row
            If cell.Value <> rowHeader And cell.Value <> "Grand Total" Then
                'Do whatever it is you want to do
                Debug.Print "Process " & cell.Value
            End If
        End If
    Next cell
End Sub


Here is a solution using a dictionary to deal with the duplicates.
I placed the output into a messagebox but you can do whatever with them from that point.
    Dim i As Long
    Dim lr As Long
    Dim dict As Object
    Dim total As Long
    Set dict = CreateObject("Scripting.Dictionary")
    
    With Sheets("Sheet1") ' Change to your sheet name
        lr = .Cells(.Rows.Count, 1).End(xlUp).Row
        For i = 2 To lr
            If .Cells(i, 3).Value = "Yellow" Then
                total = total + 1 'get a running total of yellows
                If Not dict.exists(.Cells(i, 2).Value) Then ' Create new key for unique values
                    dict.Add .Cells(i, 2).Value, 1
                    
                Else ' Increment duplicate values
                    dict(.Cells(i, 2).Value) = dict(.Cells(i, 2).Value) + 1
                End If
            End If
        Next i
    End With
    
    'Just to print them out
    Dim key As Variant
    Dim msgstr As String
    For Each key In dict
        msgstr = msgstr & key & ": " & dict(key) & vbNewLine
    Next key
    msgstr = msgstr & "Total Yellows: " & total
    MsgBox msgstr

